# How do I import a module from another project in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to to refer a old project module for the new project is there any possible way for referring the module easily.

```
project1/
    folder1/
        main.py
        secondary.py-----------
    folder2/                  |
        test.py               |
                              |
project2/                     |
    folder1/                  | 
        main1.py              |
            <------------------
```

Since, I tried to append the path,

I can't import it

```
import sys
sys.path.append('project1/folder1/secondary.py')


from project.folder1 import seconday

or someother formats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append the Python *file* to the path, append the path where the entire *package* is located in. For example, if both of your projects are in a `projects` folder like so:

```
~/Documents/projects/project1/
~/Documents/projects/project2/
```

Now you would do:

```
sys.path.append('~/Documents/projects')
from project1.folder1 import secondary
```

You can also provide a relative path and use [`sys.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to convert it:

```
sys.path.append(sys.path.abspath('../..'))
```

Comment: While it's technically legal and _sometimes_ the right thing to do, messing with `sys.path` is most of the time the wrong solution - better to edit your PYTHONPATH environment variable (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: I have quite mixed feelings about that. If this is a large, important project that @Guna33 is working on, the correct solution would be to package `project1` properly and manage it with `pip`. If it's a small user specific one-time script, then does it really matter whether you modify `sys.path` or not. Maybe if it's something in between, a thing you use quite a bit but that you're not gonna distribute to others?

Comment: actually (assuming that both projects are applications which seems to be the case given the `main` modules), the proper thing to do would be to extract the common code to a separate library, package this lib and install it in both projects's virtualenv (or equivalent) using pip (or equivalent).

Comment: Yeah, but like I said, if this is a small user script and Guna33 might just be learning Python or messing around, that's a huge overkill and there's nothing wrong with modifying the path directly.

Comment: I totally agree on this - but 1/ we don't know enough on the context and 2/ the primary goal of SO is to build a reliable technical knowledge base, not to encourage "copy-paste programming" - so answers should be as general as possible and promote best practices.  Teaching someone to use `sys.path` is fine, but a proper answer should also mention PYTHONPATH and when (and why) use one or the other.